# pywhatkit : KeyError: 'DISPLAY' from pywhatkit Library on Linux

Tags: package-management, ssh, python, email

I am able to run this code on the spyder (python 3.9), but when I run same code on the Linux. It is giving

> KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

**Python code**

```
import pywhatkit

sender = "++++++@gmail.com"
password = "password"
sub = "Subject of the mail"
message = "This is a test email"
receiver = "++++++@gmail.com"
pywhatkit.send_mail((sender), (password), (sub), (message), (receiver))
```

**output on Linux**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.main import print_sleep_time, check_window, sendwhatmsg, sendwhatmsg_to_group, sendwhatmsg_instantly, info, playonyt, search
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pywhatkit/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 673, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```